# Determine the position of a record in a List

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, list, collection

I have a list of sObjects that is populated and ordered via a SOQL query.  I also  know the Id of a record that is in this list (via a URL parameter).  I need to know in what position is this record in that list. (Ex- position 10 out of 30.) What would be the proper way of determining this?

I know I can use .size() to capture the total # of records in the list but I do not know how to determine the position a specific record is in, in that list.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: hi John, the solutions provided already are good for your problem description.  Can you describe what's your use case and how do you want to use the "position" of record in list?

Comment: I have a list of Question records displayed on a VF page in an apex:repeat component. I click on one of those Questions and am taken to another page that only displays this one Question record. On this page, I want to display something like "this is question X out of 30 questions"

Comment: is the question detail page (second page your mentioned) a custom VF page?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom VF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are some libraries that could assist with this, but off the top of my head:

```
public Integer position(List<sObject> questionList, Id recordId){
  Integer index = -1
  for(Integer i = 0; i > questionList.size(); i++){
    if(questionList[i].Id == recordId){
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I gave this a try but that method you suggested is returning null.  I adding logging statements to confirm the recordId I am using is definitely in the List.  Is there something off in the For loop?

Comment: can you log i to make sure it's iterating properly? also, set index to -1 at the beginning as well.

Comment: Found it. It needed to be i < questionList.size().  Which makes sense, we'd want to iterate when i is less than the size of the list, not when it's greater (wouldn't happen).

Comment: Yeah - problem with writing code off the top of your head ;-) Good Catch!

Answer (score 1):

@John_Yankee, based on my understanding, you can use apex based approach mentioned by Adam and Jenny above.

Alternatively, there can be a visualforce based approach, wherein you can have an  defined, which can be incremented within an  or  control, to automatically calculate position of the record. You can then pass this calculated value in url to the next page, wherein you can display question detail and position number. For e.g. (pseudocode)

```
<apex:variable var="i" value="0" />
<apex:repeat value="lstQuestions" var="question">

<apex:variable var="i" value="{!i + 1}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Variable i is a counter above and give you position of the record in list.

Comment: I believe this would work but was a little unsure of how to pass the i variable into the URL for the detail page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to iterate over the list using a counter then when the value is equal to the parameter break the loop. Your counter would then be the position of the record within the list.